# IIS Authorization Rules versus File System Security

Tags: .net, windows, iis, active-directory, authorization

I've got a site in IIS that I'm trying to restrict according to the requesting user's Active Directory groups.

Currently I'm restricting access via Authorization Rules in the web.config file.

```
<authorization>
    <allow roles="DOMAIN\primaryGroupName" />
    <allow roles="DOMAIN\secondaryGroupName" />
</authorization>
```

However, I'm trying to understand if it's necessary to also lock down the site's directory on the file system by adding these same AD groups there. Or are the URL Auth rules sufficient?

[image: file system security]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question here, for posterity/the sake of future viewers who stumble across this. In hindsight, the answer is simpler than I was originally making it out to be.

Leverage URL authorization wherever you're trying to gate access to a portion of your site that's accessible via IIS; file system ACLs are generally overkill.